# Quadratic form over real number field

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers, quadratic-forms

I have to turn the quadratic form over real number filed in normal form. I'm stuck trying to find similar problems on the internet but couldn't.

$F(x) = x_1^2-3x_3^2-2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3-6x_2x_3$

[Quadratic form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyZ4P.png)

Comment: Do you mean for a number field taking a basis $K = \sum_j a_j \Bbb{Q}$ with $\sigma_i$ the complex embeddings we have a quadratic form $q(\sum_j x_j a_j) = \sum_i |\sigma_i(\sum_j x_j a_j)|^2 = x^\top M x$  ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2415278/265466. Can’t mark it as such because MathJax processing in the pop-up is hanging my browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bring quadratic form to canonical form using Lagrange's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415278/bring-quadratic-form-to-canonical-form-using-lagranges-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to complete the square in $x_1$:
$$ \mathbf{x_1^2} -3x_3^2\mathbf{-2x_1x_2}+\mathbf{2x_1x_3}-6x_2x_3=(x_1-x_2+x_3)^2+p(x_2,x_3),$$
with
$$ p(x_2,x_3)=-x_2^2-3x_3^2-4x_2x_3.$$

Now, you iterate and complete the square in $x_2$ in $p(x_2,x_3)$:
$$-\mathbf{x_2^2}-3x_3^2\mathbf{-4x_2x_3}=-(x_2+2x_3)^2+x_3^2.$$

From here you conclude that the standard form is

$$ y_1^2-y_2^2+y_3^2=0,$$

where the new coordinates are defined by $y_1=x_1-x_2+x_3$, $y_2=x_2+2x_3$, $y_3=x_3$.

Answer (score 0):

let $\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
x_{3}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$, 
then the form quadratic is:

$q(\vec{x})=\vec{x}^{t}A\vec{x}$, hence:

$q(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & \\ 
-1 &0  & -3 & \\ 
1 & -3 & -3 & \\  
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
x_{3}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$, then you can find new 
coordinates  diagonalizing the matrix.